# How to solve patterns

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's take an example of the pattern

$T_1 = 1$

$T_2 = 6$ // $T_2 = 1 + 8 - 3 = 6$

$T_3 = 15$ // $T_3 = 6 + 12 - 3 = 15$

$T_4 = 28$ // $T_4 = 15 + 16 - 3 = 28$

If you noticed, the pattern is $T_n = T_{n-1} + 4n - 3$

So, is there a way to solve this without recursion?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're even asking. Could you be a little more specific? Also, 2 does not equal 6. Also, you should try to use LaTeX.

Comment: Even if I interpret this as $T_n = T_{n-1}+2n+1$, the results don't tally with yours for 15 and 28. You will need to explain this much clearer if you are to get any sensible answers.

Comment: What is your value of $T_0$?

Comment: This looks like $n (2 n-1)$, without expressing with any recurrence relation.

Comment: Recursion is the best way of solving it.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: I have utterly failed to find an interpretation of your "2 does not equal 6" that is not pedantic and condescending. Regarding LaTeX, this question came from a stack exchange site that is not MSE; it's entirely reasonable for the question to not be formatted in LaTeX. And since someone is probably going to do it anyway, there's no need to point it out. (In general I am against comments asking an OP to reformat their post when they are new and the question is clearly readable, *especially* when it would be easy for the commenter to reformat the post emself.)

Comment: Sorry @EricStucky, but I think many people here will find a statement like $2=6$ quite ridiculous, and asking for clarification really doesn't seem condescending to me, at least.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I just noticed the mistake just now, allow me to fix it.

Comment: Ok, I finished it.

Comment: As @RonGordon mentions above, this recurrence relation reduces to $T_n = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n}(4k-3) = 2n^2 - n$.  Are you looking for a particular solution or a general method of solving recurrence relations?

Comment: @augurar I'm sorry, I'm not good with math that much anymore, for some weird reason, maybe it's because I slept only for 5 hours, I'd prefer both though, I wish to both know what and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solve:

$$T(n) = T(n-1) + 4n - 3$$
Thus

$$T(n) - T(n-1) = 4n - 3$$

since the difference of $$T(n) - T(n-1)$$ is linear ($4n-3$ is a linear term): the original function $T(n)$ must be quadratic.

Why?

Consider an arbitrary quadratic

$$H(n) = an^2 + bn + c $$

$$H(n) - H(n-1) = an^2 + bn + c - a(n-1)^2 -b(n-1) - c = $$
$$an^2 + bn + c - a(n^2 - 2n + 1) - b(n-1) - c = $$
$$an^2 + bn + c - an^2 + 2an - a - bn + b - c = $$
$$bn + c + 2an - a - bn + b - c = $$
$$c + 2an - a + b - c = $$
$$2an - a + b$$

if $2a = u$ and $b - a = k$ then we get an arbitrary linear function $un + k$. Thus if the difference of two functions is linear the original recurrence function is quadratic.

Coming back to the problem at hand:

$$2an + b - a = 4n - 3$$
$$2a = 4 \rightarrow a = 2$$
$$b - a  = -3 \rightarrow b - 2 = -3 \rightarrow b = -1$$

$$T(n) = 2n^2 - n + c$$
$$T(1) = 2 - 1 + c = 1 + c = 1 \rightarrow c = 0$$

$$T(n) = 2n^2 - n$$

Comment: This method can be generalized to any type of polynomial recurrence

Comment: It's far easier to notice that $T(n) = T(1) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (T(j+1)-T(j)) = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (4j+1) = 1 + 4(n-1)n/2 + (n-1) = 2n^2-n$.